# Why Microsoft have two type of character set's ?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unicode, character

All application need multi language support then why Microsoft visual studio have two type of character set's

please clarify me, thanks in advance.

Comment: "All application need multi language support" what's your source?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore It's true that a lot of applications don't need multilanguage support.  A lot of what I do at present outputs tables of doubles to Excel; there's no text involved at all.  And if your program is generating tax declarations for the French government, your output has to be in French (and to support another country, you'd have to rewrite the program completely, because tax laws are so different).  But I use UTF-8 even when I need multi-language support, and others prefer UTF-32 (which MS doesn't support).

Comment: @nijansen It's not just legacy programs which use `std::string`, rather than `std::wstring`, despite what Microsoft says.

Comment: @HansPassant that question is about that character set my question is why VS have a two type of character set ok.

Comment: Yes, that's what that question is about.

Comment: @HansPassant see this ,
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/07/08/mfc-support-for-mbcs-deprecated-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it's not just Microsoft.  C++03 required two character
sets.  (Formally, I think they can be identical, but I don't
know of an implementation on a general purpose machine where
they are.)  C++11 requires 4 (`std::string`, `std::u16string`,
`std::u32string` and `std::wstring`); regretfully, it doesn't
require u16 and u32 versions for the iostream (but that will
doubtlessly come).

Different applications have different trade-offs.  In the
application I'm currently working on, we restrict the character
set to what was traditionally called ASCII, so `wchar_t` would
just make things bigger (and so things down, because of less
locality).  In the text applications I do (or did) on my own
time, I used UTF-8 internally; it's no more complex than UTF-16,
and for what I do (where international characters are only
allowed in a few specific contexts), also requires a lot less
space.  If I were doing full text processing (say an editor),
I'd almost certainly use UTF-32.

As it happens, the choice of 16 bit `wchar_t` turned out to be
a bad choice, as full Unicode requires at least 21 bits.  (When
Microsoft made the choice, of course, it seemed like the best
idea, since Unicode was still 16 bits.)  Most other systems
(which adopted Unicode much later) have a 32 bit `wchar_t`.
(The exception is IBM, which also adopted Unicode very early.)